# MySQL link columns using primary key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, Aircraft, and Flights. Aircraft contains detailed information on each aircraft that has been detected. Flights has a column that is 'AircraftID' which is also in Aircraft. In Flights, I need to populate 'ICAO' with the data from 'ModeS' from Aircraft.

```
Aircaft
 + AircraftID +  ICAO + Other Data +
 |     1      | TEST  |  *DATA*    |
 +---------------------------------+

 Flights
 + AircraftID +  ICAO + Other Data +
 |     1      |       |  *DATA*    |
 +------------+-------+------------+

SELECT * FROM Flights; +-------->  1,TEST,*DATA* #Expected output
```

Hopefully all this makes sense. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple [inner join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) query. I highly suggest you read up on joins and the different styles since they're fundamental to how SQL works.

```
select
  *
from
  flights
  join aircraft
    on flights.aircraftid = aircraft.aircraftid
```

The `join` keyword names which table you're joining to the join tree. Then, the `on` keyword specifies which field(s) you're using to join the first table to the second.

Comment: Thanks. Will this write this to the Flights table? I can't test right now as I can't import the CSVs. It is saying it import 5000 rows, but there is nothing there...

Comment: No, this is a select statement, it doesn't write anything.

Comment: `select` statements retrieve data. `insert` and `update` information write data.

Comment: Can someone help me form the 'INSERT'/'UPDATE querry? I have spent over a day trying to fix it, and cant quite get it to work.